# SVGs don't appear in Safari

Tags: svg, safari

I have svg icons, but in Safari they simply don't appear.
I was looking 2 hours for the answer and couldn't figure out how to fix it so far.
I believe something wrong with my svg files, because I was trying using other svg files and they worked.

[SVG icon sample](http://cl.ly/2p2G440Z1E31)

Comment: Please include the code in your question so that future visitors can benefit if the linked page is ever taken offline. You should also take a look at this [browser compatibility chart for SVG](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).

Comment: As you mentioned I think there is an issue with that SVG, opening it in Illustrator gives the following error: "Clipping will be lost on roundtrip to Tiny". Which settings did you use to export from Illustrator?

Comment: @block14 here is my settings http://cl.ly/image/0X0Z1U461y28 , I don't think it has something to do with my settings, because I experimented a lot with them while seeking help and using recommended ones. Also all browsers work great with my current svgs except safari. Probably it has something to do with a way I am creating my svgs. I am exporting vector objects such as paths, shapes, texts to pdf from photoshop. Then I open this pdf in illustrator and then I export this image to svg.

Comment: Instead of type "Adobe CEF", try "Convert to outline". Which version of Safari are you having issues with? Play around with the layers as well, sometimes during the conversion process they'll get reordered. Additionally FX are not always exported correctly.